# Pass DOM nodes to Polymer as attributes

Tags: javascript, dom, polymer

Ok, so I'm defining a polymer object like this:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">

<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="content">
  <template>
  <div class="someclass">
    {{content}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  Polymer({});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Which works fine if I instantiate it as:

```
<my-element content="test"></my-element>
```

However, I'd like to be able to pass HTML inside the element. If I do this:

```
<my-element content="<div>test</div>"></my-element>
```

The HTML is not added to the DOM, but displayed as text. Is it possible to pass HTML inside a polymer element? Or am I doing something completely wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some hackish code I made that may answer your question.

http://jsbin.com/hedutu/edit?html,output

Basically, I created an observer for an attribute that accepts DOMs in string format and then inserted that dom into a local dom node.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that does work. However it does seem very hackish. Am I doing something wrong in my approach? Should I handle the task of passing html inside my overlay differently?

Comment: Back in 0.5 you can actually pass DOM objects directly via template binding. However in v1.0 this changed due to perf reasons. You can still pass them as properties via js though. Here's another approach, but this time you can bind events to the dom that's to be added etc. before you can pass it to the element. http://jsbin.com/cojoge/edit?html,output

Comment: Alright thanks. I finally realised that the best way was probably to use the <content></content> tags to introduce html.